# ColorDict and DictData / Stardict development

Tags: android, dictionary

ColorDict is an Android app which accesses dictionaries in the stardict format. These dictionaries can be downloaded as a 'DictData' application: the dictionary copies itself on the SD card, after which the DictData app can be deleted.

This seems a good way the way to go about developing a dictionary app but I cannot find any information regarding either the status of ColorDict (open source?) or the DictData format. Can I build a DictData file and upload it to the Android market?

Any information welcome, as well as pointers to other options for dictionary integration (I would prefer to reuse a dictionary application and export/distribute the dictionary only).

Comment: As already mentioned Colordict uses the StarDict format and you can convert many open formats to stardict using `dictconv` or `makedict` - both are available in standard Linux repositories or are easily compilable from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should look into [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/) instead -- it's a better Android app, runs on Windows and Linux systems too (there seems to be work going on to port it to Mac), it *is* open-source, and it can work with many different dictionary formats, including stardict and babylon etc.  I've written tonnes of dictionaries that all look and work beautifully in GoldenDict.

Comment: The android version of GoldenDict is not at all open-source - in the free version you can only use up to four dictionaries.

Comment: @ccpizza - you're right.  the paid version of GoldenDict is actually the only Android app I've ever bought (even though I didn't need the extra functionality -- I just wanted to support the developers of such an awesome project).

Comment: besides android goldendict _not_ being open source, colordict has a nicer layout of dictionary contents, and also includes online wikipedia. So both are great apps indeed

Answer (score 4):

Format for StarDict dictionary files - [babiloo project at code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/babiloo/wiki/StarDict_format)

Comment: Thanks, do you have more info about the other aspects of my question?

Comment: At this moment I don't have any other information.
Maybe later when I'll try to create own dictionary.